# What is the better approach to refactor this code without mutating the state directly?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any better approach to refactoring this code without mutating the state directly? I have tried to use the spread operator but somehow the page got stuck.

```
const [workforcePlanList, setWorkforcePlanList] = useState<
WorkForcePlanPermissionType[]>([]);

const changeFromGridCard = (data, index) => {
  workforcePlanList[index] = data;
  const activeEmployeeWithoutAction = workforcePlanList.filter(
  (x) =>
    x.Employee.StatusEnum == EmployeeStatusEnum.Active &&
    !x.IsAdmin &&
    !x.IsCreate &&
    !x.IsView,
);
  setSaveDisable(isSameList() || activeEmployeeWithoutAction.length > 0);
};

const onClose = (employeeId, index) => {
  workforcePlanList?.splice(index, 1);
  const activeEmployeeWithoutAction = workforcePlanList.filter(
  (x) =>
    x.Employee.StatusEnum == EmployeeStatusEnum.Active &&
    !x.IsAdmin &&
    !x.IsCreate &&
    !x.IsView,
);
  setSaveDisable(activeEmployeeWithoutAction.length > 0);
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of mutating your state here? Is it to make the code following the mutation act upon the updated `workforcePlanList`? Do you actually want to mutate it, or are you just mutating it so that you can set `setSaveDisable()` correctly (or do you want to also have the `workforcePlanList` state updated to include the new `data` value [as in your first example] and exclude `i` [as in your 2nd example])?

Comment: I want to change the value of the state as well. I want to remove the clicked data from the list and set setSaveDisable() to display the rest by clicking on a close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying the list like this:

```
const changeFromGridCard = (data, index) => {
  const updatedList = [...workforcePlanList];
  updatedList[index] = data;

  const activeEmployeeWithoutAction = updatedList.filter(
    (x) =>
      x.Employee.StatusEnum === EmployeeStatusEnum.Active &&
      !x.IsAdmin &&
      !x.IsCreate &&
      !x.IsView
  );

  setWorkforcePlanList(updatedList);
  setSaveDisable(isSameList() || activeEmployeeWithoutAction.length > 0);
};

const onClose = (employeeId, index) => {
  const updatedList = workforcePlanList.filter((_, i) => i !== index);

  const activeEmployeeWithoutAction = updatedList.filter(
    (x) =>
      x.Employee.StatusEnum === EmployeeStatusEnum.Active &&
      !x.IsAdmin &&
      !x.IsCreate &&
      !x.IsView
  );

  setWorkforcePlanList(updatedList);
  setSaveDisable(activeEmployeeWithoutAction.length > 0);
};
```

Comment: @Abin if the answer helped, please mark it as the correct answer.